# Installing spaCy on wind 10 not working

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, python-3.6, spacy

I have Python 3.6.5 and I am trying to install spaCy via pip which is throwing me the below error when it tries to compile murmurhash.mrmr extension:

```
C:\Users\muthu>pip install C:\Users\muthu\Downloads\Installers\en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz --no-cache-dir
Processing c:\users\muthu\downloads\installers\en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting spacy>=2.0.0a18 (from en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading spacy-2.0.11.tar.gz (17.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 17.6MB 1.2MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in c:\users\muthu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
Collecting murmurhash<0.29,>=0.28 (from spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading murmurhash-0.28.0.tar.gz
Collecting cymem<1.32,>=1.30 (from spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading cymem-1.31.2.tar.gz
Collecting preshed<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 (from spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading preshed-1.0.0.tar.gz (89kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.0MB/s
Collecting thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1 (from spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading thinc-6.10.2.tar.gz (1.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 786kB/s
Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 (from spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pathlib (from spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz (49kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 629kB/s
Collecting ujson>=1.35 (from spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading ujson-1.35.tar.gz (192kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 695kB/s
Collecting dill<0.3,>=0.2 (from spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading dill-0.2.7.1.tar.gz (64kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 950kB/s
Collecting regex==2017.4.5 (from spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading regex-2017.04.05-cp36-none-win32.whl (237kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 245kB 910kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt in c:\users\muthu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1->spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1->spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading tqdm-4.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 893kB/s
Collecting cytoolz<0.9,>=0.8 (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1->spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading cytoolz-0.8.2.tar.gz (386kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 389kB 741kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six<2.0.0,>=1.10.0 in c:\users\muthu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1->spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
Collecting termcolor (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1->spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting msgpack-python (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1->spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading msgpack-python-0.5.6.tar.gz (138kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 774kB/s
Collecting msgpack-numpy==0.4.1 (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1->spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading msgpack_numpy-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyreadline>=1.7.1 (from dill<0.3,>=0.2->spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading pyreadline-2.1.zip (109kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 768kB/s
Collecting toolz>=0.8.0 (from cytoolz<0.9,>=0.8->thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.1->spacy>=2.0.0a18->en-core-web-sm==2.0.0)
  Downloading toolz-0.9.0.tar.gz (45kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.2MB/s
Installing collected packages: murmurhash, cymem, preshed, tqdm, toolz, cytoolz, plac, pyreadline, dill, termcolor, pathlib, msgpack-python, msgpack-numpy, thinc, ujson, regex, spacy, en-core-web-sm
  Running setup.py install for murmurhash ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\muthu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\muthu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-biubjhck\\murmurhash\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\muthu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-tvo0bjqa-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash
    copying murmurhash\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash
    copying murmurhash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash\tests
    copying murmurhash\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash\tests
    copying murmurhash\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash\tests
    copying murmurhash\mrmr.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash
    copying murmurhash\mrmr.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash
    copying murmurhash\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash\include
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash\include\murmurhash
    copying murmurhash\include\murmurhash\MurmurHash2.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash\include\murmurhash
    copying murmurhash\include\murmurhash\MurmurHash3.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\murmurhash\include\murmurhash
    running build_ext
    building 'murmurhash.mrmr' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\muthu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\muthu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-biubjhck\\murmurhash\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\muthu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-tvo0bjqa-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\muthu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-biubjhck\murmurhash\
```

I then installed "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools" from http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools (eventhough I had VS2012!!!) and that installation went fine!

Opened new command prompt and retried the pip, gave the path to the vs installed path and retried and so and so forth. Every time its giving me the same error. Not sure what am I missing here :(

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you're stuck and can't get it to compile, you can find pre-compiled wheel installers for all of the relevant libraries here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

You can download the file, and then do `pip install path/to/file.whl`, and it should work.

You could also try using conda, and then installing from the conda-forge channel.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a day trying to fix it recently. My solution was to install Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 (make sure that Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.... is installed,it doesn't matter if you have older versions but if you already have Microsoft Visual C++ 2017, then that will stop you from installing C++ 2015).
When you install VS2015, in the Features tab, make sure you tick the box for Windows and Web development so this is installed as well (Spacy installation 
won't work without it)
After installation, run your command prompt (I use Anaconda Prompt) as Administrator and proceed to run "pip install -U spacy".

FYI, I used Anaconda Prompt, Window 10, Python 3.6.2 and I installed Spacy on an Anaconda virtenv. Hope this would help.

[Installation step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgb6r.png)